# Why is my page scrolling to the top when click on a field and the keyboard appears?

Tags: visualforce, salesforce1-app, ios, scrolling

I have the following problem on iOS devices. When I click on an input field and the keyboard appears my page scrolled to the beginning/top. The problem occurs only on iOS devices and it occurs after I have scrolled down bit on the page.

P.S. the page is i.e. the account edit\new page but it is overridden with a custom one. On the original page everything works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like it could be this long-standing Visualforce issue:
https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000T2oL

A workaround script run after the page has fully loaded usually helps to stabilize the page (simplified to remove User Agent check that is included in link):

(function(){try{
var s=document.createElement('style'); 
s.innerHTML="html,html body{overflow: auto;-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;}body{position:absolute;left:0;right:0;top:0;bottom:0;}"; 
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s);}catch(e){}})();

Comment: Yeah, it is and I found a solution to it here is the link to the solution https://bitbucket.org/snippets/appirioux/nyyek